# Dynamic content not writing in docx on deployment server using Django rest framework. Working fine on local machine

Tags: django-rest-framework, mandrill

Below are the steps.

1. fetching "static/tac_template.docx" template file from the static folder which contains 4 Fields that need to be replaced at run time.
2. Fetch all the paragraphs from that file and replace these fields with dynamic data.
3. After filling dynamic fields save that file in static folder by company Name.
4. Convert that file to pdf and save it in same static folder
5. By Using mandrill send an email with pdf attachment.

This Works on Local machine but not on deployment server.

Below is the code.

```
def send_practice_welcome_email(user_id):
    practice = models.Practice.objects.select_related("user").get(user_id=user_id)
    temppath = create_docx(practice)
    context = emails.PracticeWelcomeContext(
        company_name=practice.company_name,        
        tips_url=settings.PRACTICE_TIPS_URL,
        benefits_url=settings.PRACTICE_BENEFITS_URL,
    )
    file_template=f"static/tac_template_"+practice.company_name+".pdf"

    attachment_dict= {"file_name": "tac_template_"+practice.company_name+".pdf", "file_path": file_template, "mime_type": "application/pdf"}
    return mailer.send(emails.PRACTICE_WELCOME, practice.user.email, context, files_to_attach=[attachment_dict])

def create_docx(instance):
    tac_accepted_snapshot = JSONField(null=True)
    tac_template_path = f"static/tac_template.docx"
    if not os.path.exists(tac_template_path):
        raise FileNotFoundError

    doc = Document(tac_template_path)    
    paragraphs = get_all_paragraphs(doc)
    
    tac_accepted_snapshot = generate_tac_snapshot(instance)
    fill_paragraphs_with_data(paragraphs, tac_accepted_snapshot)    
    
    company_template_path= f"static/tac_template_"+instance.company_name+".docx"    
    doc.save(company_template_path)  
    pdf_file=convert_docx_to_pdf_EmailAttachment(company_template_path)    
    return pdf_file

def convert_docx_to_pdf_EmailAttachment(path):
    process = subprocess.check_output(["libreoffice", "--convert-to", "pdf", "--outdir", "/app/backend/static", path])
    filename = re.search("-> (.*?) using filter", process.decode())
    if filename is None:
        raise LibreOfficeError(process.stdout.decode())
    return filename.group(1)

def generate_tac_snapshot(practice):
        date_format = "%d %B %Y"
        timestamp_format = "%d %B %Y, %H:%M:%S %p"
        date = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        return {
            "[Date]": date.strftime(date_format),
            "[Company.Name]": practice.company_name,
            "[Company.Reg.No]": practice.company_registration_id,
            "[Contact.Name]": practice.contact_full_name,
            "[Timestamp]": date.strftime(timestamp_format),
        }

def get_all_paragraphs(doc):
    paragraphs = list(doc.paragraphs)
    for table in doc.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                paragraphs.extend(cell.paragraphs)
    return paragraphs

    
def fill_paragraphs_with_data(paragraphs, data):
    for paragraph in paragraphs:
        for key in data:
            if key in paragraph.text:                
                paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace(key, str(data[key])) 
                paragraph.style.font.name = FONT_NAME
```

Comment: Is there an error message? Stack trace? System log?

Comment: @mike :not maintain any log.